Multiple Turtlebot3 SImultaion in ROS2 Humble with namespce
I am trying to launch multiple turtlebots in the same gazebo world using ROS2 Humble and autonomously control them using namespaces.
But so far, I couldn't find any good tutorials or videos for it. There are multiple for ROS1 but no good ones for ROS2.
If anyone has already did that or has an idea, that would be a great help. Thanks!

I did this a couple of years back, and I remember it was horrible. You can see the implementation in this github, both for a gazebo simulation and an implementation on actual robots.
It is using ros2 galactic, though, but hopefully you can use it as a starting point. Best of luck!
